# Able to connect to college wifi network but not able to access internet

Tags: wireless, networking, internet

My college has captive portal and I am able to connect to the network but not able to access internet. I have tried everything but nothing works. Here are my details:

```
C.E.T
 type: 802-11-wireless
 status: connected
system name: wlan0
Ipv4 address: 172.17.5.137
connection speed: 36Mbit/s
MAC address: 68:A3:C4:CB:09:5E
Access point(SSID):CET
signal strength:59%;
channel:1(2412 Mhz)
Security: WEP
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, Try opening up an **internet browser**, sometimes you have to log in to the router through a webpage. They do this for security I believe.

Comment: i tried that but the login page of captive portal isnt even loading

Comment: Hmm, well then unfortunately I can't help you, sorry.